error on loading PowerShell module dbatools
I have a script that collects some information about a SQL Server instance using the great dbatools module. The script is started from a web application. It used to work just fine, but something must have changed in the web application, and now I get an error that I can see using the dev tools in my browser (pressing F12): "detail": "{'definition': ErrorDetail(string='QS-Check for the Instance: S-SQL-XXX-03', code='error'), 'errors': ErrorDetail(string='The PowerShell module dbatools could not be loaded.', code='error'), 'result': ErrorDetail(string='Error', code='error')}"
The PowerShell-script works like ever without a problem when started standalone.
The problem happens here:
        try
        {
        # Set defaults just for this session
        set-dbatoolsconfig -name import.EncryptionMessageCheck -value $false -PassThru 
        | register-dbatoolsConfig
        Set-DbatoolsConfig -FullName sql.connection.trustcert -Value $true
        Set-DbatoolsConfig -FullName sql.connection.encrypt -Value $false
        Import-Module dbatools -Force    
        Import-Module sqlserver -Force             
    }
    catch
    {
        $error[0].Exception.Message | Out-File  "C:\temp\QSLog.txt" -Append
        $table.result = "Error."
        $table.errors = "The PowerShell module dbatools could not be loaded."
        throw $table
    }

As I mentioned, it used to work for a while. How can I investigate this error deeper?

Looks like it stores the actual error message in "C:\temp\QSLog.txt" - have you looked there?

You are having issues connecting the the server.  I would use SQL Server Management Studio to connect to server.  Than check the log file which you can find in the SQL explorer under Management. You should see a login when you run your PS script.  The login will show a user and group that was used to login.  I suspect you have some credential error with the login.

Why are you using dbatools and the native SQL server module? You are just asking for trouble in my book. I use dbatools myself and the native SQL server module handles things very differently. Nulls being one of them. Which version of DbaTools are you using? If it's 2+ you might need Set-DbatoolsInsecureConnection -SessionOnly in your script.
